# Running 'activator ui' throws ClassNotFoundException with Play 2.3.2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

After installing activator 1.2.7 and running the following command from the installation directory:

```
./activator ui
```

The following `UsefulExeption` exception is thrown:

```
kevin@comp:~/applications/activator-1.2.7$ ./activator ui
Checking for a newer version of Activator (current version 1.2.7)...
   ... our current version 1.2.7 looks like the latest.
FOUND REPO = activator-local @ file:/home/kevin/applications/activator-1.2.7/repository
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/UsefulException
    at activator.Global$.<init>(Global.scala:12)
    at activator.Global$.<clinit>(Global.scala)
    at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:106)
    at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:87)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.UsefulException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

If I run `activator ui` as super user with `sudo` the issue doesn't appear. I want to be able to start the activator ui with normal privileges.

Running `ls -lah` in the activator folder products the following output:

```
kevin@ubuntu:~/applications$ ls -lah ./activator-1.2.7
total 1.2M
drwxr-xr-x   4 kevin kevin 4.0K Aug 10 16:11 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 kevin kevin 4.0K Aug 10 15:46 ..
-rwxr--r--   1 kevin kevin 9.5K Aug  5 17:35 activator
-rwxr--r--   1 kevin kevin 6.9K Aug  5 17:35 activator.bat
-rwxr--r--   1 kevin kevin 1.2M Aug  5 17:35 activator-launch-1.2.7.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 kevin kevin 5.8K Aug  5 17:35 LICENSE.html
-rw-r--r--   1 kevin kevin 6.3K Aug  5 17:35 README.html
drwxr-xr-x 132 kevin kevin 4.0K Aug  5 17:35 repository
drwxr-xr-x  12 kevin kevin 4.0K Aug  5 17:35 templates
kevin@ubuntu:~/applications$
```

I am using Play 2.3.2 / Activator 1.2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It appears that you're executing `activator` command as `user`, though the local library repository activator found belonged to `kevin`. Does `~/applications/activator-1.2.7` resolve to `/home/kevin/applications/activator-1.2.7/`?

Comment: Sorry, poor question asking on my behalf. I changed my username to mask it, but didn't change it further down. I'll change it back now.

Comment: you can do ls -al and checkout if you have required permissions on your activator folder.

Comment: That's a very good idea - can you `ls -l /home/kevin/applications/activator-1.2.7` and paste the output to the question?

Comment: I updated the question with the output of the `ls` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you current user don't have right privileges to access files under "/home/kevin/applications/activator-1.2.7/"

You should grant him access to those files.

Comment: The question is why does the activator need the files in the other user? How did that ever happen?!

Comment: It depends on the OS but in most case when you down load an archive from internet then unzip it all files will have -rw-rw-r-- and you cant execute them.